# reactstrap, callback hook used as ref weird behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

While trying to get a DOM element's position on render using this code:

```
const Modes = () => {

  const callbackRef = useCallback(domNode => {

    if (domNode) {

      let rect = domNode.getBoundingClientRect()
      console.log("rect", rect)
    }
  }, []);
return <>
    <Toast>
        <ToastHeader></ToastHeader>
        <ToastBody>
            <div ref={callbackRef}>  </div> 
        </ToastBody>
    </Toast>
</>
}
```

I noticed that it always prints a DOMRect object with zero for every property :[image]

If I add state dependence and then state changes causing rerender, the correct position will be printed. Something like this:

```
const Modes = () => {

  const callbackRef = useCallback(domNode => {

    if (domNode) {

      let rect = domNode.getBoundingClientRect()
      console.log("rect", rect)
    }
  }, []);

  const [show, setShow] = useState(true) // added state
  return <>
    <Toast>
        <ToastHeader></ToastHeader>
        <ToastBody> 
            {show ? <div ref={callbackRef}>  </div> : null} // div inside Toast can be toggled
        </ToastBody> 
    </Toast>
    <Button onClick={() => setShow(!show)} >toggle </Button> // added toggle button

  </>
}
```

After double click on the button:
[image]

What confuses me the most is the fact that if I replace this `Toast` imported from Reactstrap with pure html with bootstrap classes the problem disappears. And this is exactly what React renders because I copied it from source code in the browser:

```
<div class="toast fade show" role="alert">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto"></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body"> 
        <div ref={callbackRef}>  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it seems to be a problem that exists just for this `Toast` component. For Reactrstrap's `Card` for example it is not the case. So how can using a component which at the end of the day gets rendered into a certain html code be different from using the same html code and why this particular component turns out to be a special case regarding obtaining its DOMRect?